# How could you create a ultrasonic vision in Unity3d? (Bat Vision)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had the idea to create a game where you would see everything like a bat. There are some [people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWDbc2l8YlE) which have achieved something like that.

The problem is I would like to have another type of "Bat Vision". It is pretty hard to explain but if i look into one direction and then rotate the character I would still see something I looked at before.

**Explanation with timestamps:**

- Sec 0: I am looking at point A where a object is 300 meters away
- Sec 1: I rotate to point B and see an object 100 meters away
- Sec 2: I see object A and B at the same time
- Sec 3: I still see object B

**Explanation with picture:**
[image]
As you can see the player first shoots the ultrasonic waves *a* first on *A* and afterwards waves *b* on *B*. They both come back at the same time so that both objects are seen at the same time.

If you did not understand why I see objects delayed. As everyone knows sound travels with a speed about 1/3 km/s. So an object which is 300 meters in the distance would get seen after about 2 sec.

I already tried to shoot `RayCasts` or `GameObjects` into the direction and as further they are away the darker the pixel at that position will be. But as you can think... Shooting 2 million `RayCasts` every Frame is not very healthy. I was also thinking about `Shaders` but I don't know how it is possible that one still sees the `Shaders` while looking into another direction. Also I don't have much experience with `Shaders` and would need help there anyways.

I would be glad if someone has another Idea how I could create this.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this the easiest way would be using an image effect shader that accesses the depth buffer.

- The value of each pixel in your depth buffer is by definition the distance of that pixel in the world to the camera
- You can decrease the value of each pixel by some value every second and set the value to max every X seconds based on the distance given by the depth buffer... this will give the effect of sound bouncing off that object back to your player

Comment: Thanks for the Idea I will have a look at it tomorrow

Comment: Okay I searched a little bit but I am not very experienced with shaders. First of all, is this also possible with the shaderes from LWRP because they are more easy to create with the GUI and how would I exactly do that too.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKoNp2RqE9A
tweak the colors to achieve needed effect

Comment: Thats more like a wave which gets sended out so not rly what I need but I will have a closer look at it.

Answer (score -1):

It appears to me that maybe you want to duplicate any meshes and surfaces that your player has 'seen', and keep this in view with some grayish light settings. And the 'real' objects are all hidden, that is, they all have their MeshRenderer components disabled or removed.

If the player shall see an item like a shadow in front of him even though he moves, you could have the cloned visible duplicated move along with the player some time until they fade.

To find out what to duplicate I am sure you'd need a lot less raycasts than doing it for each pixel. Clone the mesh, then check visibility for each vertex and set the visibility in the duplicated vertex color and alpha.

Comment: I mean that would be an idea but if the game is big, this would cause many problems in performance I guess.